# e.preventDefault() causing webkit mobile overflow to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile-webkit

I'm trying to solve a problem that's been puzzling me all weekend.

On mobile webkit (Safari iOS 5.1 in, my case) I'm unable to keep the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` behavior working when I place anything in the body that disables default behavior.

```
$('body').on({
    touchmove : function(e){
        //e.preventDefault(); // I played with these as well
        //e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The reason for `return false` above: I do not want the body to move when you swipe on it, as is the default mobile safari behavior.

**Fiddle 1** - the touch overflow works in the middle box with all the text, but the body moves as well, which I do not want:
http://jsfiddle.net/MeLxg/1/

**Fiddle 2** - the body is now fixed by returning false on it's mousemove event, but the overflow does not work anymore, you can't scroll the text box:
http://jsfiddle.net/MeLxg/2/

QR codes for your convenience (it's mobile, after all, use your scanner)

**Fiddle 1** view panel only [image: http://jsfiddle.net/MeLxg/1/show/] http://jsfiddle.net/MeLxg/1/show/

---

**Fiddle 2** view panel only [image: http://jsfiddle.net/MeLxg/2/show/] http://jsfiddle.net/MeLxg/2/show/

Comment: I'm a dork - I had the URL wrong. it's not `/view/`, it's `/show/` - it's fixed now

Comment: You should delete this post, as it's doubtful that internalized problem will be helpful to anyone.

Comment: @bwheeler96, what are you talking about? It's a genuine problem and applies to anyone interested in developing web-clip apps for iOS. If you want to keep a "native app" feel, you have to remove the safari default behavior for body swiping.

Comment: I think from his point of view he's trying to say that *because* it was an issue with the URL, that people that have a similar issue but have the URLs right won't find this of help.

Comment: That was what I was pointing out, but theres always a chance I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need to change things around a bit. Your code is doing exactly what it should be doing. Since the body encapsulates whatever item your applying the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` to, that scrollable div or whatever will fail to scroll, since its in the body. Perhaps you can get a similar effect by creating a dummy element simply to span the full device width and height that will catch any touchmove events outside of this div you want scrolling.

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/MeLxg/3/

```
// added html
<div id="stopTouch"></div>


// added css 
#stopTouch{
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%; 
   width: 100%;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.1); // just so i can see its filling the screen
}

// changed js
$('#stopTouch').on({
    touchmove : function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, because this question is quite old. But I came here looking for a solution that I have just found. Maybe it helps someone.

I had the same problem, needed to keep the preventDefault behavior of not moving the body, but wanted a nice -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; for a div.

So, aply event.preventDefault with:

```
<script>document.ontouchstart = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); } </script>
```

then in the div that you want to scroll:

```
<div class="nicescrolldiv" ontouchstart="document.ontouchstart = function(e){ return true; }" ontouchend="document.ontouchstart = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }" style=" overflow: scroll !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;"></div>
```